# Renaming files with no extension to random files {1,2...}with an extension

Tags: bash, file-rename

I saw how to rename many files at once and changing their extensions, like this example

`$ rename -v 's/\.htm$/\.html/' *.htm
3.htm renamed as 3.html
4.htm renamed as 4.html
5.htm renamed as 5.html`

The only problem as you know in Linux, it doesn't need extensions, so my files are without them and want to add jpg extension to them at the same time giving them random number name like 0.jpg, 1.jpg ...

If you could give me a simple bash command to do it and thank you.

Comment: Are your files all of the same kind or has the file type to be detected?

Comment: the file type is deleted (no file type)

Answer (score 2):

random file names may have overlaps, if you want use sequential numbers you can try something like this (assuming the files are in the current directory)

```
$ touch some files without extensions
$ ls
extensions  files  some  without

$ i=0; for f in *; do mv ${f} $((i=++i)).ext; done
$ ls
1.ext  2.ext  3.ext  4.ext
```

Comment: Thank you Cyrus, It worked as a charm.
Thank you too Karakfa, yours as well worked as a charm.
I tried both solutions and they worked well for me, just the first one I had to install mmv (It was not in my machine).

Comment: well... Cyrus deleted his/her answer.